# Customizing placehorlder in billing/shipping forms

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, placeholder, account

I am using `woocommerce_checkout_fields` filter for customizing the placeholders in WooCommerce checkout page.

```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
  function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['placeholder'] = 'Name';
    $fields['billing']['billing_last_name']['placeholder'] = 'Surname';
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['placeholder'] = 'Email';
    $fields['billing']['billing_company']['placeholder'] = 'Company Name';
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['placeholder'] = 'Phone';
    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['placeholder'] = 'Zip Code';
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['placeholder'] = 'City';

    $fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name']['placeholder'] = 'Name';
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name']['placeholder'] = 'Surname';
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_city']['placeholder'] = 'City';
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode']['placeholder'] = 'Zip Code';
    return $fields;
  }
```

This work fine only for checkout page form.

How to customize 'placeholders' in all shipping and billing forms?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean in **My account** pages for Billing and Shipping form, the only filter hook (that I know) that could do the trick is:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_args', 'custom_form_field_args', 10, 3 );
function custom_form_field_args( $args, $key, $value ) { 
    // your code 
    return $args;
};
```

It is located in [**wc-template-functions.php on line 1734**](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_form_field.html#1734), triggered by `woocommerce_form_field()` function in woocommerce templates under `my_account` subfolder, `form-edit-address.php` file (displaying the form fields) .

---

This are the default `$args` you can use to target the changes you want to do inside your filter function:

```
$defaults = array(
    'type'              => 'text',
    'label'             => '',
    'description'       => '',
    'placeholder'       => '',
    'maxlength'         => false,
    'required'          => false,
    'autocomplete'      => false,
    'id'                => $key,
    'class'             => array(),
    'label_class'       => array(),
    'input_class'       => array(),
    'return'            => false,
    'options'           => array(),
    'custom_attributes' => array(),
    'validate'          => array(),
    'default'           => '',
);
```

> **NOTE: With some changes made by [Stone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6291646/stone) it's working.** *(see the comment)*.

**USE:**
You could use 'placeholder' this way to target each placeholder you need to change:

```
if ( $args['id'] == 'your_slug1' ) {
    $args['placeholder'] = 'your_new_placeholder1';
} elseif ( $args['id'] == 'your_slug2' ) {
    $args['placeholder'] = 'your_new_placeholder2';
} // elseif … and go on
```

The placeholders are generally the same for billing and shipping address… So your code will be like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_args', 'custom_form_field_args', 10, 3 );
function custom_form_field_args( $args, $key, $value ) { 
    if ( $args['id'] == 'your_slug1' ) {
        $args['placeholder'] = 'your_new_placeholder1';
    } elseif ( $args['id'] == 'your_slug2' ) {
        $args['placeholder'] = 'your_new_placeholder2';
    } // elseif … and go on 

    return $args;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! @LoicTheAztec your solucion is perfect, I use the 'id' field like this `if ($args['id'] == 'billing_first_name')
      $args['placeholder'] = 'Name';`