# Woocommerce overwriting Shipping City Select Field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

We are attempting to modify the default Woocommerce Checkout Shipping City Field using the documented methods on [docs.woothemes](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) but have run into an issue.

We have replaced the `shipping_city` text field with a `select` dropdown menu.

On page load the `select` dropdown menu is replaced with the default text field and if available is autofilled with the users previous delivery destination.

However, if the page is reloaded/refreshed the text field is then replaced with the new and much desired `select` dropdown menu.

We have filtered the field using several WordPress `add_filter` functions and changed `priority` both up and down (-999 to 999).

We have run the `filter` both inside and outside of our Shipping Method `Class`

We have even disabled the browser auto form complete because we… well ran out of other ideas…

When the `select` field is working… it works well. The Shipping costs get updated, data gets returned, stored and emailed.

The `filters` used are:

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', array( $this, 'fn_name' ) );`

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', array( $this, 'fn_name' ) );`

and the `$field` array looks like:

```
$fields[ 'shipping' ][ 'shipping_city' ] = array(
                    'label' => __( 'Suburb/City', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'required' => FALSE,
                    'clear' => TRUE,
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'options' => $options_array,
                    'class' => array( 'update_totals_on_change' )
                );

                return $fields;
```

Oddly, when we ran two filters on the same field; the label of the sendond was overwritten by the first… go figure… Gee I wish I knew Ajax… i think its Ajax but then if I knew AJAX I'd know if it was Ajax…

WordPress Version 4.5.2 && WooCommerce Version 2.5.5

***Addendum regarding final accepted solution:***

The code suggested and supplied by @LoicTheAztec worked very well and has been included in our implementation.

However, the issue was caused by our original inclusion of the $field filter inside of our Shipping Method Class which is hooked into the shipping_class_init

To correct the issue we have moved the new woocommerce_form_field_args filter into a seperate file and retrieved our options array after the new Shipping Method Class has worked its magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work with `woocommerce_form_field_args` hook, this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_args', 'custom_form_field_args', 10, 3 );
function custom_form_field_args( $args, $key, $value ) { 
    if ( $args['id'] == 'billing_city' ) {
     $args = array(
            'label' => __( 'Suburb/City', 'woocommerce' ),
            'required' => FALSE,
            'clear' => TRUE,
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => $options_array,
            'class' => array( 'update_totals_on_change' )
        );
    } // elseif … and go on 

    return $args;
};
```

This are he default `$args` parameter values:

```
$defaults = array(
    'type'              => 'text',
    'label'             => '',
    'description'       => '',
    'placeholder'       => '',
    'maxlength'         => false,
    'required'          => false,
    'autocomplete'      => false,
    'id'                => $key,
    'class'             => array(),
    'label_class'       => array(),
    'input_class'       => array(),
    'return'            => false,
    'options'           => array(),
    'custom_attributes' => array(),
    'validate'          => array(),
    'default'           => '',
);
```

References:

- [Customizing placehorlder in billing/shipping forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601551/customizing-placehorlder-in-billing-shipping-forms/37603801#37603801)
- [Add custom css class to WooCommerce checkout fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943791/add-custom-css-class-to-woocommerce-checkout-fields/36724593#36724593)

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec – Initial tests look promising… ajax is throwing a hissy fit but we will run a few variations and see if we can resolve that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code into your child theme function.php and should do the job

```
$city_args = wp_parse_args( array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => array(
        'city1' => 'Amsterdam',
        'city2' => 'Rotterdam',
        'city3'  => 'Den Haag', 
    ),
), $fields['shipping']['shipping_city'] );

$fields['shipping']['shipping_city'] = $city_args;
$fields['billing']['billing_city'] = $city_args; // Also change for billing field

return $fields;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'jeroen_sormani_change_city_to_dropdown' );
```